# one div over two others but operating only on one of them

Tags: css

Hi I'd like to do something like this:

outlook on divs
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_Dgiq7dtZEdXpZdlpMaTY2cFU/view?usp=sharing

div settings are just for a better understanding of which is which:

```
  div1 - z-index: 1; background: red;
  div2 - z-index: 2; background-image: url('triangle.png');
  div3 - z-index: 3; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
```

div3 is only operating / covering div2.

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use relative or absolute positioning, that should be doable. Unless you mean you want div3 to cover div2 but not div1...

Comment: YES exactly I want Div3 to cover Div2 BUT NOT Div1

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible — you cannot make one part of an element higher on the z-index than another element (above the stack), and make another part the lower (under the stack). Think of z-index as layers of paper laid out horizontally. What are you trying to achieve here? If you can describe your scenario and intended function/use, there might be other approaches, such as clip paths.

Comment: I think, It is possible to do, by using one image with triange shaped hole.

so the layers would have to be placed like this:
at the bottom div2, then div3 and at the top div1 with image with triangle shaped hole.

Comment: you can achieve this probably using `:before` and `:after`

Answer (score 0):

You can arange div like in picture you posted. 
DIVs are stacked by z-index and it is entirely above layer with lower z-index (area that one div cover will hide all elements below them). So if element have z-index = 3 it will be entirely above elements with lower z-index.

```css
div{
    position: absolute;
}
div.base{
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
div.triangle{
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 100px 200px;
    border-color: transparent transparent grey transparent;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
div.top{
    z-index: 3;
top: 100px;
left: 150px;    
opacity: 0.4;
border: solid 1px black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: white;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 50px, 0px 100px, 100px 100px, 100px 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for Your reply. Your solution would work if it didn't matter that div3 covers both div1 and div2 with its colour. my intention though is that div 3 would cover only div2 disregarding div 1

Comment: I edited code above and add clip to top layer (for chrome). With clip you can cut element to custom shape but it need some math to calculate position of polygon points. If you need to move layers around you will have a lot of calculations :o)